# Tezbox wallet does not show TZ1 wallet balance

Tags: staking-balance

I have Depected 9.5 XTZ into the address of TZ1 wallet and was recorded on the blockchain, but when I checked the balance in Tezbox wallet, I did not see the balance like picture.

My TZ1: tz1VAu5zNGnNSXpLySdy8LR64xQqW7MMtKkF

What should I do?

[image: balance dose not show]

Comment: Tezos Stack Exchange is meant for specific technical questions. Wallet and other product support inquiries should be directed either at the proper support channels or asked on Tezos Telegram, Riot, Reddit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can migrate to Galleon.

A previous answer used a fake address for Galleon.

Google "Galleon Tezos"

https://cryptonomic.tech/galleon.html

Another usual advice is to change the rpc setting in tezbox to another node such as https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io.